# calcalute gradient degree - css

Tags: html, css, sass

**Hello** How to calculate gradient clockwise degree in different vendor prefixes, I need calculate it because linear-gradient and -webkit-linear-gradient don't give me the same result:

**Here my code:**

```
@mixin diagonal-gradient ($deg, $startColor, $startColorLoaction, $endColor, $endColorLoaction) {
background: $startColor;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient($deg, $startColor $startColorLoaction, $endColor $endColorLoaction);
background: -moz-linear-gradient($deg, $startColor $endColorLoaction, $endColor);
background: -ms-linear-gradient($deg, $startColor $endColorLoaction, $endColor $endColorLoaction);
background: -o-linear-gradient($deg, $startColor $startColorLoaction, $endColor $endColorLoaction);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient($deg, $startColor $startColorLoaction, $endColor $endColorLoaction);
background: linear-gradient(180 + $deg, $startColor $startColorLoaction, $endColor $endColorLoaction);
}
```

Comment: You don't need vendor prefixes anymore

Comment: why I don't need vendor prefixes

Comment: Because browser support for gradients is pretty decent now, hence, you don't need to worry about vendor prefixes

Comment: Sorry, but still didn't get your requirement :) A demo or something might be helpful here.

Comment: Here the problem [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EigoaamqTwg&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: This will be helpful, read the angle part in the doc - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: thank you very much, I will check it

Comment: I agree with @Mr.Alien that you don’t need to worry about the difference in vendor prefixes: http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-grad. Just use the plain `linear-gradient`.